# Push to UINavigationController from AppDelegate via remote notification

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

My initial view controller is a tab bar controller, in the tab controller there are several UINavigationControllers, in one of the UINavigationControllers a modal is presented where another UINavigationController is created with another flow of UIViewControllers.

I need to respond to a received remote notification in the App Delegate by pushing to one of the “deepest” parts of that view hierarchy.

I can recreate a UINavigationController and launch the proper UIViewController by name, however it leaves the user high and dry with no other place to go.

Is there a way to get the user back into the proper flow of navigation?

Answer (score 4):

The way I got this to work, in the didReceiveRemoteNotification method of my App Delegate:

```
let rootTabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as UITabBarController

let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let firstNavigationController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("firstNavVc") as UINavigationController

rootTabbarController.viewControllers![0] = firstNavigationController

let vControllerForFirstNavController = (rootTabbarController.viewControllers![0] as UINavigationController).topViewController as MainViewController

let firstDetailsNavController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("detailsNavController") as MainDetailsMenuNavigationController

let detailsVc = firstDetailsNavController.topViewController as MainDetailsViewController

firstNavigationController.presentViewController(firstDetailsNavController, animated: false, completion: nil)

let specificInfoVc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("sDetails") as SpecificDetailsViewController

firstDetailsNavController.pushViewController(specificInfoVc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Just a quick note, in my applicationWillResignActive method, I had to set the root window to the first tab bar controller that I used above - this way if the user leaves the application a few levels deep but then taps on a notification from outside the app the app will now be at the first level